# String para um array dentro de um loop - javascript/nodejs

Tags: javascript, array, string, node.js, loop

eu quero passar as strings de um arquivo txt para um array e assim que cada linha fosse passada para o array o programa iria executar ele normalmente, dai depois ele repetia e pegava a segunda string do arquivo txt. Tudo está sendo feito em javascript/nodejs só que ja faz 2 dias que estou parado nisso e não consigo sair do canto.

codigo do loop com o arquivo e o array:

```
function email_parser(){
var fs = require('fs');
var email_count = "";
var array = [];

var array = fs.readFileSync('email.txt').toString().split("rn");
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    email_count = array[i];
}}
```

e o estou chamando a variavel deste jeito

```
email = email_parser();
```

Obrigado!.

Answer (score 0):

Estás a separar as linhas da maneira errada, tens de usar "\".

Testa assim:

```
.split(/\n/).map(line => line.trim());
```

Comment: Não funcionou :/

Comment: @jorleidedasilva tira o `.toString()`, o `. readFileSync` já te dá uma string.

Comment: @jorleidedasilva se ainda não conseguiste dá-me um exemplo do texto, ou coloca o ficheiro online para poder criar um exemplo para veres.